# How can I disable the default Konsole shortcut (CTRL + ALT + T)?

Tags: kde, opensuse

This key combo is used in my IDE and I don't use Konsole, so I want to disable it as a global shortcut for launching a new terminal window. I'm unable to find any setting for it in KDE's three sections of keyboard shortcuts or Konsole's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under openSUSE 15.2, go to:
System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts > Other Shortcuts > KDE Daemon > Launch Konsole

On Kubuntu 20.04: System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> KDE Daemon -> Launch Konsole

On other distros:
System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> System Settings -> Launch Konsole

[image]